# Calculate percentiles based on dates in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, distribution, percentile

I have a table with 50k rows that has column A (BIGINT, example customer account ID) and column B (Date, example - last purchase date).

I would like to understand what % of customers made their last purchase in the top 25%tile, top 50%tile, 75%tile of the given date range, so I can tell based on all these customer account IDs where the majority of our last purchases are skewed to. Any thoughts on how to achieve in sql?

Table: alltransations

```
ACCT_ID         |   DATE
----------------|---------------
23748234782947  |   05-15-2016
28178792839838  |   05-01-2016
28178092734538  |   02-12-2016
28347732839867  |   01-15-2016
28170909362959  |   10-10-2015
28171334099090  |   11-11-2015
28109129330023  |   12-25-2014
28172377859289  |   10-31-2014
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got you right with the tiles, but if you mean by dividing up the timerange into four regions it would work like this for an interval from 2016-02-01 to 2016-06-01. Tradeoff : manually calculation of the intervals; possible one can do this thru date calculations, too

```
CREATE TABLE tblA ( ACCT_ID INTEGER, PDATE DATE);

INSERT INTO TblA(ACCT_ID, PDATE) VALUES (1000,'2016-05-21');
INSERT INTO TblA(ACCT_ID, PDATE) VALUES (1001,'2016-05-11');
INSERT INTO TblA(ACCT_ID, PDATE) VALUES (1002,'2016-05-24');
INSERT INTO TblA(ACCT_ID, PDATE) VALUES (1003,'2016-04-21');
INSERT INTO TblA(ACCT_ID, PDATE) VALUES (1004,'2016-02-12');
INSERT INTO TblA(ACCT_ID, PDATE) VALUES (1005,'2016-02-21');
INSERT INTO TblA(ACCT_ID, PDATE) VALUES (1001,'2016-03-22');
INSERT INTO TblA(ACCT_ID, PDATE) VALUES (1002,'2016-04-01');
INSERT INTO TblA(ACCT_ID, PDATE) VALUES (1005,'2016-04-01');
INSERT INTO TblA(ACCT_ID, PDATE) VALUES (1006,'2016-04-01');

    SELECT DISTR.DATE_RANGE, COUNT(DISTR.ACCT_ID) / OVRL.TOTALCNT
FROM (SELECT 'TOP25' as DATE_RANGE, A.ACCT_ID
        FROM tblA A
       WHERE A.PDATE BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01.05.2016', '%m/%d/%Y')  AND STR_TO_DATE('01.06.2016', '%m/%d/%Y')
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'TOP50' as DATE_RANGE, B.ACCT_ID
        FROM tblA B
       WHERE B.PDATE BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01.04.2016', '%m/%d/%Y')  AND STR_TO_DATE('01.06.2016', '%m/%d/%Y')
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'TOP75' as DATE_RANGE, C.ACCT_ID
        FROM tblA C
       WHERE C.PDATE BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01.03.2016', '%m/%d/%Y')  AND STR_TO_DATE('01.06.2016', '%m/%d/%Y')
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'ALL' as DATE_RANGE, C.ACCT_ID
      FROM tblA C
      WHERE C.PDATE BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01.02.2016', '%m/%d/%Y')  AND STR_TO_DATE('01.06.2016', '%m/%d/%Y') ) DISTR
,    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTALCNT FROM tblA A WHERE A.PDATE BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01.03.2016', '%m/%d/%Y')  AND STR_TO_DATE('01.06.2016', '%m/%d/%Y')) OVRL
GROUP BY DISTR.DATE_RANGE, OVRL.TOTALCNT
```

will deliver

```
ALL 10  10
TOP25   3   10
TOP50   7   10
TOP75   8   10
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will dynamically create date quartiles based on the full date range of your data set, then displays the percentage of IDs that occurred in the quartile:

```
select unix_timestamp(min(date)) into @start from p;
select unix_timestamp(max(date)) into @end from p;
Set @25 = 0.25 *(@end - @start)+@start;
Set @50 = 0.50 *(@end - @start)+@start;
Set @75 = 0.75 *(@end - @start)+@start;

SELECT 
CASE WHEN unix_timestamp(date)>@75 then 4
WHEN unix_timestamp(date)>@50 then 3
WHEN unix_timestamp(date)>@25 then 2
ELSE 1 END as Quartile, 
round(count(id)/(select count(*) from p)*100,2) as Percentage 
FROM p 
GROUP BY Quartile;
```

[Here is a functional example](http://rextester.com/OTJGT29248) with a little more detail and formatting.

If you have half of your dates at the beginning of your range and half at end, you will only see Q1 and Q4 dynamically.

First set variables as the range, then split for each Quartile, or other time segment partition.

The `CASE` statement cascades from large to small dates, all in `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` format for easier arithmetic, being passed from Quartile to Quartile as it fails.

This same structure can be used to split date ranges by segment, n-tiles.